# Is there a way to use python packages on computers that don't have them installed

Tags: python, package

I need to use the `PIL` package for a program I'm developing at school, but my school doesn't have `PIL` installed on their computers so it always raises an `Import Error`. I bring my code in via USB and the `PIL` package is installed in a virtual environment in the folder which the code is in (with all the other necessary files).

Is there a way for python to recognise the location of the package on the USB?

(P.S. the school's system blocks you from entering the command line and the teachers won't allow me to install the package on the system)

Comment: Since you won't have access to `pip` or anything on the command line, seems like you'd want to use something like pyinstaller. Have you looked into that or anything else?

Comment: Yes; your USB device is peripheral storage, just like the hard drive at school.  Add the USB drive's path to your PATH variable, so Python will know to search there.

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried using pyinstaller and py2exe but the application would close as soon as I opened it (at home). I couldn't find a solution so I gave up on it

Comment: @Prune I can try that but I would think that that's blocked by the system too

Comment: Well, that circles back to you and your system at school.  You would need to discuss your problem with your system administrators -- we do not know the restrictions, let alone how they intended to support user-supplied packages.  It's quite possible that they intend to ban all such packages.